# How to calculate the amount of psi needed to pull a 150lb object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, pressure, air, lift

I am working on a project, and I wanted to know how to calculate the amount of psi I would need to apply to a wheel-like mechanism (Like in a pneumatic torque wrench) to be able to pull a 150lb object up off the ground.